# JS - if something take longer time than x then do something

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to do something if an action (data loading) takes longer than some particular time?

For example, you have some loading visual element on your page just in case data loading takes more time than normal. 99% of loadings are immediate so this element just FLASH which is kind of irritating.

Is it possible to do something like: If loading takes more than one second => show loader ?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it possible.

Comment: Yes,.  loading is normally, (should be), asynchronous.  So just setup a timer that triggers if something is not returned in a set amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two configurable inputs here, the **time to wait before showing** the loader (the delay), but also a **minimal duration** for the loader to avoid any flash.

If you set the delay to 1s, but your data arrives after 1.1s, then you will show your loader for only 100ms and thus you will get a flash, so the miminum duration is also important.

Here is an example implementation using `setTimeout`. You can configure the `delay` and `minDuration` to get the behaviour you want.

The `loadingAnimation()` function must be called to start the animation process. It returns a `stopAnimation()` function that must be called once your async action is finished. Here the fake async function takes this `stopAnimation()` function as argument to call it in a `setTimeout`.

```js
const loader = document.querySelector('#loader');
const status = document.querySelector('#status');

const hideLoader = () => loader.style.display = 'none';
const showLoader = () => loader.style.display = 'block';

function loadingAnimation(delay = 500, minDuration = 1000) {
  let minDurationDone = false;
  let asyncActionDone = false;
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!asyncActionDone) {
      showLoader();
      setTimeout(() => {
        minDurationDone = true;
        if (asyncActionDone) {
          hideLoader();
        }
      }, minDuration);
    }
  }, delay);
  
  const stopAnimation = () => {
    asyncActionDone = true;
    if (minDurationDone) {
      hideLoader();
    }
  };
  
  return stopAnimation;
}

function fakeAsyncAction(doneCallback, delay) {
  status.innerHTML = 'Started';
  setTimeout(() => {
    status.innerHTML = 'Done';
    doneCallback();
  }, delay);
}

function trigger(delay) {
  const stopAnimation = loadingAnimation();
  fakeAsyncAction(stopAnimation, delay);
}

hideLoader();
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#loader {
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  border-top: 5px solid #3ad;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="trigger(300)">Trigger super short async action (300ms)</button>
<button onclick="trigger(700)">Trigger short async action (700ms)</button>
<button onclick="trigger(1500)">Trigger long async action (1500ms)</button>
<p>Async action status: <span id="status"></span></p>
<div id="loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, through a combination of a variable of a sufficiently high scope and a timeout.

Some pseudocode to illustrate this:

```
var showLoader = true;

myAjaxCall({
    'onSuccess': function() {
        showLoader = false;
    }
});

window.setTimeout(function() {
    if(showLoader) {
        // Show loader here
    }
}, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
```

It should be noted this assumes your ajax is asynchronous.